# Best Practices for Activity Flow in Android Applications

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Trying to understand best practice for the lifecycle of my android application, and how activities fit into it.

For example, I have a main activity, sort of the "home" of my application.  But, on start-up there are several activities that I 'might' need to run, depending on several cases, one being that it is the first time the app's been run.

Is best practice to call these 'start-up'/house-keeping activities FROM my 'home' activity?  Or should the application begin with a 'house-keeping' activities, do the work, then finish() and start the 'home' activity?

Thanks for advice about this,

-- J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set your `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` on whatever the user will most likely want to go to from their home screen. Presumably, that would be your "home" activity.

In `onCreate()` of that activity, make the determination if there is some other activity that is needed (e.g., "first-run"), and call `startActivity()` on it. When the user presses BACK from there (or you `finish()` that new activity), control will return to your "home" activity.

Answer (score 3):

For the best user experience (and cleaner code), you really shouldn't chain Activities.

A good best practice for the scenario you describe (needing a particular layout of options on first-launch) is to set a SharedPreference the first time that the "Home" Activity is created. In the same `Activity.onCreate()` call you should make a decision about what your UI will display based on that saved value (e.g., either set the appropriate View's visibility to `View.GONE` or choose a different layout.xml altogether).

As an added bonus: You can overload a hypothetical "has been opened" SharedPreference with the version number of the app (e.g., `LastOpenedVersion`) to be able to present the user with a change log the next time they open your "Home" activity after an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to start from a splash screen `Activity` (rather than a "home" one), which then determines what to launch next.

You should also consider if your start-up/house-keeping needs to be accomplished via an `Activity`.  If it is not something that the user interacts with, then you can move that functionality into a `Service` that runs a separate thread.